# UnityStandaloneFileBrowser: ArgumentException Mono.WebBrowser is referenced by System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, dll, argumentexception

I imported the UnityStandaloneFileBrowser asset to a sample project to test it. Unfortunately I am not able to build the project for Windows.

I needed to set the Scripting Backend to IL2CPP and tried to use .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.X, but both gave me these errors while trying to build:

**1. ArgumentException**

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly Mono.WebBrowser is referenced by System.Windows.Forms ('Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/Plugins/System.Windows.Forms.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

**2. UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent**

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 3 seconds (2740 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

**3. UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException**: 3 errors

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <33fb8f3984d146e083d756d969c06738>:0

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Has anyone an idea, what I can do to fix this?

I contacted the asset developer a few times, but I don't get a response. So you are my last hope :-)